# Post image link with Facebook C# SDK problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I try to post my image link to Facebook fan page using Facebook C# SDK.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(this._accessToken);
dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
parameters.link = "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/260418_185563101499189_124421460946687_425466_2105002_t.jpg";
parameters.picture = "http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/260418_185563101499189_124421460946687_425466_2105002_t.jpg";
parameters.name = "My Picture";
parameters.caption = "My Picture Caption";
parameters.description = "";
dynamic result = client.Post("{Fan page ID}/feed", parameters);
```

An error occur like below.

> (OAuthException) (#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream:
>   http://photos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/260418_185563101499189_124421460946687_425466_2105002_t.jpg

But if i set "picture" parameter to empty string it work perfectly.

How could i fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook doesn't allow you to re-post or hot-link images that are hosted on their CDN.  They added this policy and error message back in [June 2010](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=238529).  You will need to upload this photo to some kind of non-Facebook server or photo sharing site and then use that url.

Comment: Thank you. But if i still want to post image link just like used on Facebook (paste url that have image, it will show that image and description). Is there a way to do it.
PS. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Sorry dont quite understand what you are asking.

Comment: In facebook you can do like this image --> http://www.mediafire.com/i/?wtmpejcn1et3xiw. So i want to develop program that automatic do like this for every 2 hr.

Comment: Based on that error message and that forum discussion you would need to 1) download image from Facebook using C# WebClient 2) Save to your web server or use WebClient to upload image to your a site like mediafire 3) post to Facebook API using mediafire/server url. address.